# get data from last week

Tags: php, mysql

I want all data from last week.
I used

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

but its not working when my week starts with "Monday".

What should I do?

Comment: The problem is you're using current date, not "monday" or whatever as you start point. so on thursday it would run between 6 days ago and yesterday..

Comment: I want that if I start from whatever date it should always display last week starting from monday to sunday.

Comment: Exacrtly you havent taken into account that today is not Monday.

Comment: @BugFinder This sql return data with starting from sunday to monday. but I want monday to sunday.     
 
if I use +5 it work for only if current date is sunday, but when I change date its not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE date  >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+7) DAY  AND date   <  CURDATE()  - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY
```

I try this and it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Then change like this

```
$lastweek = unix_to_human(time("Y-m-d H:i:s") - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60), TRUE, 'us');
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE date >= curdate() - $lastweek
AND date < curdate() - $lastweek
```

Comment: if I use +5 it work for only if current date is sunday, but when I change date its not work.

Comment: my project in cakephp here unix_to_human returns an error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method AdminStatisticController::unix_to_human()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE YEARweek(date) = YEARweek(curdate())
```