# MySQL query to get data for the last week

Tags: mysql

I want  to run a MYSQL query to get data for the previous week. The datatype for the date column is DATETIME. Could anyone suggest?

Comment: Hmm, I think your question might suffer from posting/editing issues. Please clarify or read the FAQ.

Comment: Previous week? or last seven days?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493995/get-data-from-last-week , And typecast your datetime to date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740612/query-to-convert-from-datetime-to-date-mysql

if it was what you were searching for, then my opinion is do some more google :)

Comment: For the last seven days...

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM calendar 
 WHERE dt BETWEEN CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another version:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I find most reliable for getting data between the previus monday to the current monday. (That is what most people mean when the say past week, but not all, and that reflect in mysql).

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   table 
WHERE 
   date BETWEEN 
      (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL -1 WEEK - INTERVAL WEEKDAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) DAY 
      and 
      (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 WEEK - INTERVAL WEEKDAY((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) DAY
```

It's also easy to change it for another week intervall

Answer (score -1):

Make variable for current datetime - 1 week and make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > $datatime
```